300 random marbles are thrown in one of 100 boxes. What is the probability that the i-th box is empty?
So there are 300 random marbles and $100$ random boxes, they are independent of each other. Each random marble is thrown in one of the $100$ boxes. I have to compute
1)the probability that the $i$-th box is empty and
2)the expected value of how many boxes are empty.
So, if the probabilities of marbles being thrown in random box is evenly distributed, then X - a marble being thrown in box, $P(X=X)=\frac{1}{100}$.
So we choose random variable $Y - $ a marble falls into $i$-th box. Then Y is distributed after Bernoulli distribution. Then $$E[Y]=\frac{1}{100}\cdot 300=3.$$From there it follows that the expected value of marbles in a $i$-th box is 3. But this value gives no lead as to how to proceed with the question. My only solution:
1)Let X - how many times the marbles are thrown until the marble falls into the i-th box. Then $X ∼ Geometric(p = 1/100)$. Then the probability that only 301th marble will fall into i-th box is $\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{300}\cdot \frac{1}{100} \approx 5\cdot10^{-4}.$

Let's define random variable $Y-$marble falls into i-th box. Then $Y∼Bernoulli(p=\frac{1}{100}). $Then from there $E[Y] =100.$So it is expected that 100th marble will fall into the $i$-th box. Honestly, I don't have any idea as to how to find the solution for this problem, so any help will be greatly appreciated!


Stuffing together a bunch of identical Bernoulli trials and counting the successes gives the binomial distribution, where the probability of getting $k$ successes on $n$ trials each with probability $p$ is
$$\binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
Where the binomial coefficient $\binom nk$ is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$
Conveniently, most of the harder calculation goes away when $k = 0$, leaving just $(1-p)^n$.
The probability that a particular box is empty is then $0.99^{300} \approx 0.049$.
We can then calculate the expected number of boxes using linearity of expectation, so for $100$ boxes each with emptiness probability $0.049$, we should expect about $100 \times 0.049 \approx 4.9$ empty boxes.
